# Zypper packages status flag explanation

Tags: package-management, opensuse, suse, zypper

As I am working on automating the patch process on a Suse machines. I would like to get a clearer image on the packages status lifecycle.

First of all, I am trying to list the available patches and their new version, simply by running:

```
$ zypper list-updates
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'NON OSS Update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Warning: Repository 'OSS Update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
S | Repository | Name          | Current Version      | Available Version    | Arch
--+------------+---------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------
v | OSS Update | libkmod2      | 17-16.1              | 17-19.1              | x86_64
v | OSS Update | libsgutils2-2 | 1.43+43.158502d-18.1 | 1.43+46.4b09c76-21.1 | x86_64
v | OSS Update | libssh2-1     | 1.4.3-19.6.1         | 1.4.3-19.9.1         | x86_64
v | OSS Update | libtasn1      | 4.9-3.1              | 4.9-6.1              | x86_64
v | OSS Update | libtasn1-6    | 4.9-3.1              | 4.9-6.1              | x86_64
```

It is shown that the Status is **"v"**

After that, I am checking the packages installed, by running:

```
$ zypper packages --installed-only
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'NON OSS Update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Warning: Repository 'OSS Update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
S  | Repository | Name                              | Version                         | Arch
---+------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------
i  | OSS Update | aaa_base                          | 13.2+git20140911.61c1681-28.9.1 | x86_64
v  | OSS Update | aaa_base                          | 13.2+git20140911.61c1681-28.6.1 | x86_64
v  | OSS Update | aaa_base                          | 13.2+git20140911.61c1681-28.3.1 | x86_64
v  | OSS        | aaa_base                          | 13.2+git20140911.61c1681-27.2   | x86_64
i+ | OSS Update | acl                               | 2.2.52-11.3.1                   | x86_64
v  | OSS        | acl                               | 2.2.52-10.15                    | x86_64
i  | OSS Update | bash                              | 4.3-83.15.1                     | x86_64
v  | OSS Update | bash                              | 4.3-83.12.1                     | x86_64
v  | OSS Update | bash                              | 4.3-83.9.1                      | x86_64
v  | OSS Update | bash                              | 4.3-83.6.1                      | x86_64
v  | OSS Update | bash                              | 4.3-83.3.1                      | x86_64
v  | OSS        | bash                              | 4.3-82.6                        | x86_64

...
```

In the manual, they mentioned that **"i"** means that the package is installed while the **"v"** means that a different version is installed. But, nothing mentioned about the **"i+"**.

When I update one of the available patches, the status changes from **"v"** to **"i+"**. Does it mean that the last version of the package is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **i+** stands for user installed packages while **i** means it was installed automatically (for example as a dependency of a other package).

I think this is also mentioned in the zypper manual.

To answer your question: Yes, you have installed the newest version.

Cheers